# How does WooCommerce solve the HTTP headers already sent issue?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, http-headers

So I have a basic wordpress plugin that has a form in the admin end. The form collects information via POST and inserts a record in the database and redirect to the edit page of the object created.

Step 1: get object fields from POST array

Step 2: insert code into database using $wpdb

Step 3: if insert was successful redirect to https://example.com

```php
if( isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

    $result = $wpdb->insert('table', array('first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name), array('%s','%s'));

    if($result){
        $url = "https://example.com/";
        header("Location: $url");
        die();
    }else{
        echo "Error inserting record in table";
    }
}
```

Now the expected result is that the page should redirect to https://example.com on successful insertion of object in the database. But I get a headers already sent error in PHP.

Interestingly, if I install and activate woocommerce in WordPress, the error vanishes and the expected output is achieved.

I'm curious as to how woocommerce does it.

Comment: You must make sure, that no output has come before the header/redirect. No var_dumps, no echoes, basically, no HTML should be rendered before a header

Comment: I understand that. I think Woocommerce fixes all these issues when it is activated. I just want to know how so that I can replicate the same in my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `header()` function, you may experience these kind of warnings in WP. It's always a better approach to use [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) instead:

```
wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/' );
exit;
```

**Update:**

1. Your function containing header send/modify data (e.g. `wp_redirect`, `header()`, etc.) must be invoked before any output is made by WP. Maybe you can test putting your function and the related hook, in another function which is hooked to `init` or `admin_init` action hooks?
2. Make sure none of your plugin files has any spaces or strings before PHP opening tag (`<?php`)

Comment: Hi Yashar, I tried that but I still got the headers already sent error.

Comment: Can you post a more complete version of your code? Are you sure this redirect causes the headers already sent error and you didn't for example use a PHP ending tag in an included file? And please post the complete debug log related to this error. BTW welcome to SO :)